# Why does Webdriver.io selector "~" for accessibility id not work for a Android app, but selector "id:" yes?

Tags: android, typescript, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

**Context**
I want to try WebDriver.io for testing mobile applications.
I am using Appium 2.0, WebDriver.io and Typescript together to automate testing on Android Emulator and Real Android device.
I am also using Mocha framework.

**Encountered problem**
When I use selector for accessibility id the Tilda sign "~", WebDriver.io does not find the element in the application as it should be used according webdriver.io documentation:
https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/#accessibility-id

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "test_via_npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.6.9",
    "@wdio/utils": "^8.6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^8.6.9",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.6.9",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.6.8",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.6.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Capabilities
**

```
{
    "appium:platformVersion": "11", //13
    "appium:deviceName": "Redmi Note 8T", //Pixel 3a
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "appium:platformName": "Android",
    "appium:udid": "111111",
    "appium:appPackage": "Some package",
    "appium:appWaitActivity": "ExampleOfMainActivity",
    "appium:app": path.join(process.cwd(), "./app/android/app-prod-release.apk"),
  
    "appium:noReset": false
}
```

**Example that does not work:**

`await $('~accessibility_id')`

**This is my real testing script that does not work:**

```
describe('Sample', () => {
    it('Sample test', async () => {
    
        const allowLocationAccess = await $('~accessibility_id');
        
        await allowLocationAccess.click();

    });
});
```

**Webdriver.io log complaining about the error that element wasn't found:**

```
[0-0] 2023-04-05T19:52:59.387Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   using: 'accessibility id',
[0-0]   value: 'accessibility_id'
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2023-04-05T19:52:58.441Z INFO webdriver: RESULT []

...

[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] Sample
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0]    ✖ Sample test
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0]
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] 1 failing (11.7s)
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0]
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] 1) Sample Sample test
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] Can't call click on element with selector "~accessibility_id" because element wasn't found
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] Error: Can't call click on element with selector "~accessibility_id" because element wasn't found
```

**Examples that works:**

```
await $('id:accessibility_id');
await $('//*[@resource-id="accessibility_id"]')
await $('//*[@text="Text of the element"]')
```

**This is my testing script that does work:**

```
describe('Sample', () => {
    it('Sample test', async () => {
        
        const allowLocationAccess = await $('id:accessibility_id');
        
        
        await allowLocationAccess.click();

    });
});
```

**Webdriver.io log that says that successfully found the element:**

```
[0-0] 2023-04-05T20:22:42.489Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("id", "accessibility_id")
[0-0] 2023-04-05T20:22:42.490Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/session/7ae27aee-4e07-4174-9051-e2c0552dcc61/element
[0-0] 2023-04-05T20:22:42.490Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   using: 'id',
[0-0]   value: 'accessibility_id'
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2023-04-05T20:22:43.659Z INFO webdriver: RESULT {
[0-0]   'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '00000000-0000-00fe-ffff-ffff0000009f',
[0-0]   ELEMENT: '00000000-0000-00fe-ffff-ffff0000009f'
[0-0] }

...

[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] Sample
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0]    ✓ Sample test
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0]
[16c732eb Android 11 #0-0] 1 passing (1.8s)
```

Does anybody know why Tilda sign does not work for an Android accessibility id when WebDriver.io documentation says clearly use Tilda sign for it?